# Firebase Database Structuring Android

Tags: android, firebase

I have just started with firebase and I have many doubts regarding structuring. Just for learning I took an example (Picture 1). 
Problem statement : User will send some order. Admin will get that order. ( User can be many so admin will receive many orders). Admin confirm order with expected time. User gets expected time and confirms admin back. (I could have stopped at one way communication but I want confirmation from both side)

[image]

For this, I was planning to have structure like below:

```
Users -> User Unique Id -> Info
                        -> Orders -> Order Unique id -> Name
                                                     -> Quantity
```

Admin will read order from this flow only and later update order item with price and time.

Should I have different table for this info like below

```
Admin -> Order Unique id -> Price
                         -> Time
                         -> Status
```

How should I implement this in better way?

Comment: Check this link https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/data-persistence/firebase-firebase-structure-and-further-setup

Comment: There is no singular best way to structure data in a NoSQL database. It all depends on the use-cases you want to implement. I recommend checking our [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s), and [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video).